# Wrong package.json path when npm install in react native project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I found when I run npm install at the root of the react native project, it always show me the warn:

> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/chen/Documents/react-native/project/node_modules/node_modules/package.json'

but we know the package.json should under the node_modules folder

and this is my `package.json` in the project root

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "bundle-ios": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.ios.js  --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/bundle/index.ios.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios/bundle"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.0-rc.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and everything ok with this json, after run npm install, the library will append in dependencies.

and also has another `package.json` in node_modules foloder, and this json wont update when I run npm install, the error said it point to `node_modules/node_modules/package.json`,of course not exist this file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.9.0"
  }
}
```

So how's npm install find that wrong path??

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` module should be present in the `root` directory of your project. This is, if you want to install all the `npm` dependencies for your project.

Actually when you run`npm install`, it searches for `package.json` file, and installs all the `dependencies` written in that file. So, wherever you run `npm install` , there should be one `package.json` file in that directory.

So, for simplicity we keep the `package.json` file at the root of the `project`, so that `npm` installs all the dependencies required for that project at one go.

**Update:**

every `node module` has its own `package.json` file and `node_modules` folder, thats the way it works. `package.json` contains all the `dependencies` required for that module,and the `node_modules` folder will have those modules inside it. Again if you go one more level deep, you will find another package.json file. So, all such `package.json` contains the dependencies required for that particular `module`.

**Try to go inside the `node_modules` folder and explore it, you will understand it better.**

Comment: yes there is a `package.json` in the root. but also has one in node_module folder, so what's it use for??

Comment: did you understand what problem you were having, did my answer solve your doubt?

Comment: You can use the --prefix option to specify a path for npm install. But make sure you named the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package.json in the project root.

Then each module under node_modules has one.

But I don't think you should have a package.json in the node_modules folder

```
  /
    package.json
    /node_modules
                   <-- no package.json here
      /module1
        package.json
      /module2
        package.json
```